# Scraping music playlist Info from a dreezer api with Python

Tags: python

Is anyone familiar with Deezer API. and knows how to extract a personal music playlist info from Deezer website using their API? Here is there doc link https://developers.deezer.com/api/ i couldn't find a simple way of doing it.
I need your help to parse through lots of jargon in it, and create python code of getting that info.